# Core Data & iCloud (iOS5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, icloud

After adding a new NSManagedObject to my Core Data store I tried calling:

> ```
>     if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
> ```

and got the following exception (weirdly I had no error and the result was also positive!)

> 2013-03-15 18:32:09.753 Nick copy[28782:3407] CoreData: Ubiquity: An exception occured during a log file export: NSInternalInconsistencyException save notification contents: NSConcreteNotification 0x3891b0 {name = _NSSQLCoreTransactionStateChangeNotification; object =  (URL: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/FCAF7FC6-7DC8-4E0B-A114-38778255CA90/Documents/MyApp.sqlite); userInfo = {
>       "_NSSQLCoreActiveSaveRequest" = "";
>       "_NSSQLCoreTransactionType" = 2;
>       "_NSSQLCoreTransientSequenceNumber" = 1;
>   }}

I can catch all exceptions from the "save" method and the App runs fine. Just wondering if this is really save to do, because it feels totally unsafe.

EDIT: Another exception when trying to delete an Object:

```
Catched Exception: Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.  Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and give up on getting Core Data and iCloud to smoothly work together now, before sinking too much time into this. It's just a waste of time. If anyone has a working, stable, reliable implementation of the combination (including proper handling for duplicates and conflicts), I'd really like to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't find the thread anymore, but it told me I had to make sure to always use **NSManagedObject** classes only in the **thread/dispatch_queue in which they are created**.

The problem is, if you do access it from a different queue, it might work or crash after a random interval.

I made sure I call NSManagedObject from a dedicated dispatch_queue only and have not logged any weird exceptions since then.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe? Probably not. The error shows that the underlying ubiquity system failed to create a SQL log file. That probably means that it failed to create the transaction log that iCloud would use to sync changes. Catching it and continuing means that your data *probably* saved locally, depending on the details of the framework code. But it almost certainly means that the changes will not be synced by iCloud. Worse, you could well be in a situation where future saves will also fail for the same reason.

I'm not completely sure about the second exception but it's very likely to be a side-effect of the first one.

If you're attempting to use Core Data's built-in iCloud support on iOS5, this is just the beginning of the weird, inexplicable errors. I've done a fair amount of iCloud/Core Data work and I really can't recommend using it with iOS 5. Even iOS 6 is dicey at best, but problems are less likely than on iOS 5.

Comment: " this is just the beginning of the weird, inexplicable errors." So true. My App is still delayed to launch on App Store for these issue. How about you? Did you launch your app on market, Tom?

Comment: No, and we're exploring alternatives to iCloud.